# Laravel mutators without a matching database column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, mutators

I'm looking at updating my mutators and accessors to the [new syntax introduced in Laravel 9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) but I can't seem to make it work.

I currently have a model with a `MorphMany` relationship to a `Settings` object that acts as a key-value store. As a shorthand I'm using mutators to set a couple of more commonly used settings. Very simplified, it looks like this:

```php
class Item extends Model
    public function setSomeSettingAttribute($value)
    {
        $key = "some_setting";
        Setting::updateOrCreate(
            ["settable_id" => $this->id, "settable_type" => self::class, "key" => $key],
            ["value" => $value]
        );
    }
}

$m = Item::find(1);
// typically in a controller this would be $request->all()
$arr = ["some_setting" => 234];
$m->update($arr);
```

This works fine and the setting is updated. The important thing to note is that there is no column in the database named `some_setting`.

---

In the new code, it seems like the mutator should look like this:

```php
public function someSetting(): Attribute
{
    $key = "some_setting";
    return Attribute::make(
        set: function ($value) use ($key): void {
            Setting::updateOrCreate(
                ["settable_id" => $this->id, "settable_type" => self::class, "key" => $key],
                ["value" => $value]
            );
        }
    );
}
```

But this is not working; Laravel is attempting to insert something into the `some_setting` column, resulting in an SQL "column not found" error.

Is there a way around this that doesn't involve editing all my controller code to remove the fake columns? Or, if not, is the old mutator syntax deprecated in any way?

Comment: old mutator syntax is not deprecated and I doubt it will be. New syntax is kinda nice in the sense that you can bundle setters and getters in the same method but if you only have one of the two, it ends up just feeling like a lot of bloat for nothing.

Comment: The fact that it is no longer in the doc make me think otherwise. I have similar use case and have been pulling my hair out to make it work with the new syntax 